# NSFetchedResultsController for new object

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data, uitableview, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have UITableViewController with static editable cells. In my UITableViewController I make CoreData object, like this:

```
- (User*)user {
    if (_user == nil) {
        _user = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:TABLE_USER inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
        NSError* error;
        [self.managedObjectContext save:&error];
        if (error != nil) {
            abort();
        }
    }
    return _user;
}
```

I want to get the object in NSFetchedResultsController that would display its fields in a table, and then save the object.
I'm trying to do:

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController
{
    if (_fetchedResultsController != nil) {
        return _fetchedResultsController;
    }

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    // Edit the entity name as appropriate.
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:TABLE_USER_PROFILE inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    // Set the batch size to a suitable number.
    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"lastName" ascending:NO];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = @[sortDescriptor];


    NSPredicate* pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%@ = %@", TABLE_USER, self.user];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:pred];

    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:TABLE_USER];
    aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
    self.fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController;

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error]) {
        abort();
    }

    return _fetchedResultsController;
}
```

But it didn't work. I get empty fetchedResultsController.

Comment: What about the `NSPredicate` and `TABLE_USER`?

Comment: It's static string equals `@"Users"`

Comment: and what about `self.user`? Is it an object or a string? Could you also share the `NSFetchRequest`? Finally, maybe I didn't understand, but you want to know why the query doesn't retrieve any results, am I wrong? Thanks.

Comment: `self.user` is object with getter method `- (User*)user` described above. Also I edit my question with additional info about `NSFetchRequest`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `self.user` is a `NSManagedObject` and you query against a `User` entity you could try to edit your predicate like the following:

```
NSPredicate* pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self == %@", self.user];
```

Hope that helps.

P.S. If my answer doesn't work try to provide some other details (see my comment)